# idle TCP timeout for US carriers (or any carrier for that matter)

Tags: android, tcp, timeout

From what I understand carriers remove any tcp connections that are idle for some number of minutes. This is why if you want to maintain a persistent tcp connection from your clients to your backend, you have to send keep-alive's both ways.

My question is: what should that keep-alive interval be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, nobody can remove a TCP connection except the end-points.  That's because the IP network protocol is all that the network sees and it is stateless by design.

What makes an "end point" however may not be what you expect.  A carrier can put a transparent proxy or a router with NAT in between at which point those do need to keep state in order to properly forward the data.

NAT is your biggest problem because it's more common and if the router decides to drop the state for a connection due to not seeing traffic for a while, and endpoint will never know until the next time it tries to send data.

Enabling `SO_KEEPALIVE` has a default value of 2 hours.  A well behaved router should thus hold state for at least that long, but don't bet the farm on it.

To answer your specific question...  If it were me, I'd use 15 minutes or less.

Note that only one side need send the keep-alive as they work by re-sending the last 1 byte of the data stream as though it got lost on the network.  The receiver discards it because it has already seen it but sends a new ACK in reply thus resulting in traffic going both directions.

Comment: but afaik the SO_KEEPALIVE is not easily configurable

Comment: int delay = X;
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_TCP,TCP_KEEPIDLE,&delay,sizeof(delay));
int count = X;
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_TCP,TCP_KEEPCNT,&count,sizeof(count));
int interval = X;
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_TCP,TCP_KEEPINTVL,&interval,sizeof(interval));
int enable = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_KEEPALIVE,&enable,sizeof(enable));

Answer (score 1):

Only broken NATs will need to do this. AIUI, a sensible NAT can just send TCP keepalives to both ends of the connection when it needs to check for liveness, and drop the connection if enough of them fail to elicit a response.

Alas, many/most NATs are broken.

FWIW, iOS's "multitasking" has a "voip" feature which will un-suspend your app if your socket receives data, or optionally at approximate time intervals (for e.g. keepalives); the minimum interval is something like 300 seconds, so something between 300-1200 is probably going to work.

Answer (score 0):

As I do not know your particular reasons for why you are keeping a connection alive, even though there apparently isn't any comm traffic, 5 minutes used to be the cut off with a couple of the US based carriers (others have it longer).  You should know that they can change this value at any point, though, thus if your application is counting on that as part of its functionality things could get interesting for you if the elect to do so.

FYI ...